# Formulário perde informações passadas pelo POST

Tags: php, formulário, post

Tenho um formulário que contém ao todo 45 `textarea` (vou postar só a primeira parte aqui).

Quando envio essas informações do `form` para uma página *PHP*, que somente exibe o que foi passado por POST, parte das informações não são recebidas.

Formulário:

```
<form action="./?p=upg&f=agenda" id="autoForm" method="post">
```

Textareas:

```
<td><textarea class="w100 form-control send" rows="4" name="cp1"></textarea></td>
<td><textarea class="w100 form-control send" rows="4" name="cp2"></textarea></td>
<td><textarea class="w100 form-control send" rows="4" name="cp3"></textarea></td>
<td><textarea class="w100 form-control send" rows="4" name="cp4"></textarea></td>
<td><textarea class="w100 form-control send" rows="4" name="cp5"></textarea></td>
```

Página PHP:

```
print_r($_POST);
```

Mesmo quando preencho todas as `textarea` e envio o formulário, só exibe o primeiro elemento, os demais aparecem vazios.

> ```
> Array ( [id] =>  1 [cp1] => CAMPO1 [cp2] => [cp3] => [cp4] => [cp5] => [cp6] => [cp8] => [cp10] => [cp9] => [cp12] => [cp15] => [cp16] => [cp20] => [cp25] => [cp18] => [cp24] => [cp30] => [cp7] => [cp14] => [cp21] => [cp28] => [cp35] => [cp32] => [cp40] => [cp27] => [cp36] => [cp45] => )
> ```

Comment: Não faz muito sentido não. Deveria passar os valores :/

Comment: Seu form faz o submit puro ou tem algum script que trata os dados antes? Veja nesse [print](https://i.imgur.com/Yz4uB08.png) um script funcionando exatamente como "dito por você", com 45 campos "cp*x*"... Outra coisa: seu print_r() está retornando só 28 campos, e na pergunta você disse que são 45... Poste seu código completinho aí para vermos. Provável que tenha algo tratando esses dados e você não percebeu...

Comment: Descobri o erro. Eu realmente não sei o que ocorreu, mas, vários campos textarea estavam com nomes repetidos. Obrigado pela ajuda. Acho que fiquei tanto tentando tentando observar outras coisas que poderiam dar o erro e olhando somente para os primeiros campos que não me atentei que o PHP retornavam uma quantidade inferior de campos em relação ao que eu estava enviando. Muito obrigado.